# If any good jQuery Page Flip plugin worked find under fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flipview

I need to implement Page Flip functionality for a image gallery. But all free plugins like jPageFlipper, imBookFlip, BookBlock etc.  have examples on inline page. I tried jPageFlipper inside the fancybox but it is not loaded the canvas. If anybody know about any flip plugin have builtin functionality for opened in lightbox/fancybox like popoup. Or can work with these popup plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

BookBlock can be use inline, but you may have to tweak the CSS from their original demo.

Here's an example of bookblock being loading in a popup:
https://github.com/codrops/BookPreview